# VIM highlighting newlines in a file, how to disable?

Tags: ssh, vim, colors

I have tried installing a few new colourschemes for VIM and I have encountered a weird highlighting issue best explained with this pic:

[image: screenshot]

When opening an existing file everything is fine however when I start inserting and add new lines the new lines are highlighted (in this case Olive but with another theme it was cyan or red). If I enter new text it's not highlighted, if I enter new text then backspace so the line is empty then the highlighting doesn't reappear. It only appears on a new line. I have searched the schemes for the colours (Hex values, RGB values and names eg "Olive" but they just don't exist in the scheme files.

How do I stop this highlighting?

(Setup is using Ubuntu shell on Win10 to SSH into a raspberry pi running raspbian. vimrc is:

```
set nocompatible
set backspace=2

syntax on
filetype indent plugin on
set ts=4 sw=4
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're seeing is [a bug in Microsoft Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/832), which is used for the Windows Subsystem for Linux.  The problem is that the Microsoft Terminal claims to be the terminal type `xterm-256color`, which supports a feature called BCE, but the terminal itself doesn't support that feature.  This leads to the odd background drawing that you've seen because Vim attempts to use this feature to draw background colors and it's silently ignored.

Fortunately, Microsoft has fixed this bug, and while it's not clear which versions of WSL contain the new terminal, you should definitely update to the latest version of Windows 10 you can.  That should fix the issue you're seeing.